# Counter triggers sprites as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, sprite

How do I use the counter to trigger sprites? Need an example or idea to work from.

I want the number values to load sprites. The value of the counter goes to a text field. I want each number value to have an "if" condition to play a sprite of a corresponding number.

[alt text http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/icon_7.jpg](http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/icon_7.jpg)

**Dumb example**
//counter plays pictures rather than plays numbers in text field

**Verbose example**
//if more than 0 and less than 2, play 1 ==> ONE DISPLAYS ON SCREEN

**Comparison**
-variable data display "like Flash music visualization"
-data is a counter instead

**How it could work**
-loaders receive number values from counter
-9 targets "9 number spaces"
-add and remove child
-allows counter to look like anything

[alt text http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/icon-3.jpg](http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/icon-3.jpg)

**COUNTER I WANT TO USE**

```
//"counts to a million with two decimal places" <br>
var timer:Timer = new Timer(10); 
var count:int = 0; //start at -1 if you want the first decimal to be 0<    
var fcount:int = 0;   


timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, incrementCounter);    
timer.start();    

function incrementCounter(event:TimerEvent) {    
  count++;    
  fcount=int(count*count/10000);//starts out slow... then speeds up   
  mytext.text = formatCount(fcount);  
}  

function formatCount(i:int):String {   
     var fraction:int = i % 100;   
     var whole:int = i / 100;   

    return ("0000000" + whole).substr(-7, 7) + "." + (fraction < 10 ? "0" + fraction : fraction);   
}
```

Comment: +1 for the Count:) Ha-Ha-Ha-Ha-a-a

Comment: You ask some crazy questions dude! It's like Programming via SO.

Comment: Yea, I'm angry at life and take it out in programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to do something like this?

http://shaneberry.net/numbers/

If so, I can put a link up for the source.

Comment: Yes, that's awesome! That's what I'm after. Please put up the source.

Comment: It looks like something from Metropolis

Comment: That's just awesome. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want an on screen counter that uses a different images/sprites for each digit of the count.

You could modify formatCount to something like this:

```
var decimal_space:int = 5;  //the amount of space for the"."
var width_of_sprite:int = 16;
var decimal_digits:int = 2;
var whole_digits:int = 7;
var sprites:Array = new Array();

//this will create sprites for the whole digits from left to right
for (var i:int = 0; i < whole_digits; i++) {
  var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
  s.x = i * width_of_sprite + decimal_space;
  sprites.push(s);
  this.addChild(s);
}

//this will create sprites for the decimal digits from left to right
for (var i:int = 0; i < decimal_digits; i++) {
  var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
  s.x = (i + decimal_digits) * width_of_sprite + decimal_space;
  sprites.push(s);
  this.addChild(s);
}

function formatCount(c:int):String {   
  for (var i:int = whole_digits + decimal_digits - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    redraw_sprite(sprites[i],c % 10);
    c = (c - (c % 10)) / 10;
  }
} 

function redraw_sprite(sprite:Sprite, value:int):void {
  //add code here to redraw each sprite
}
```

Comment: I'll noodle on it, this helps with the arguments.